# awk system call with inverted effect

Tags: awk, scripting, test, system-calls

I have a data file with multiple data blocks enclosed between specific keywords (`DATA`,`END`). I am using `awk` to extract the data blocks into separate files, based on a file name taken from said block.
Since some data blocks share the same name, I am renaming each output file with an increasing integer if the file ("`blockname`") already exists:

```
#cat input.file
useless stuff1
DATA blockname1
data1
data1
END
useless stuff2
DATA blockname2
data2
data2
END
useless stuff3
DATA blockname1
data3
data3
END
useless stuff4
```

Expected would be three output files `blockname1`, `blockname2`, and `blockname1_1` (note how the last file has an integer assigned to it)

```
#cat blockname1
DATA blockname1
data1
data1
END
```

(the others accordingly...)

Now the following script works as I want it:

```
awk '/DATA/,/END/ {
     if ( $1 ~ /DATA/ )
       { block=$2 ; i=0 ; file=block
         while ( system("test ! -e " file ) )
           { i++ ; file=block"_"i ; print file }
       }
       print $0 > file
     }' input.file
```

My problem lies with the `while` loop and its system call:

I expected `system("test -e " file)` to be TRUE when the `file` exists and to be FALSE if `file` does not yet exist, i.e. the `while` loop to only start running if `file` is present and to break if (the new) `file` does not exist yet.

However if I use `system("test -e " file)` (and make it verbose with `print file`), I have an infinite loop of the same name with increasing integer suffix and the opposite `system("test !-e " file)` gives the desired result.

So this behaves exactly inverse to what I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured: the problem lies with the different definitions of what is TRUE and FALSE between the exit status of `test` and the `while` loop condition in `awk`.

A postive `test` command results in an exit code of `0` for TRUE and a negative one in `1` for FALSE.

However, in `awk` the `while` loop interprets `0` as FALSE and `1` as TRUE, so exactly the opposite definition.

As an example:

```
awk '{ while ( 0 ) ; { print "0" } }' file
```

will not produce any output, while

```
awk '{ while (1) ; { print "1" } }' file
```

will print infinite `1`s.

Best practice is thus to be explicit in such a combination

```
while ( system("command") == 0 )
```

or

```
while ( system("command") == 1 )
```

respectively.

So in my case

```
while ( system("test -e " file ) == 0 )
```

shows the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` `system()` returns an exit status of command you run - 0 for success and != 0 if not success. For simple example you can try running:

```
v = system("date");
```

v will be 0

if you run:

```
v = system("dat");
```

v might be 127 or value different from 0, the error returned from OS if dat command is missing or not found.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, the goal is extract the content of input.file into various files avoiding lose blocks with the same name.

If that's the case, and, if the target directory is always empty before the extraction, then there is a better (and faster) solution:

```
awk '
/DATA/{
    block=$2;
    n = blocks[block]++;
    file=block (n? "_" n: "");  
}
/DATA/,/END/{
    print > file
}' input.file
```

In this way awk doesn't need execute a new shell N times just to test if file exists.

Notes:

- There's no need the BEGIN block, because awk's field separator is
  already spaces.
- There's no need the `'\'` at the end of the lines,
  because the single quote is already multiline.

Comment: Well, my problem was more in understanding the "odd" behaviour of the `while` condition. However your solution is pretty neat - thank you, I prefer, this over my bulky thing. The BEGIN block is a leftover from my different file format - I forgot it becomes useless in my generic example. Leaving out the backslash will spare me some trouble. Thanks for this, too. But you are spot on regarding the script's intention. Could you explain the `n = blocks[block]++; file=block (n? "_" n: "")` part in some more detail?

Comment: The algorithm uses one array: `blocks` that is indexed by block name. Ex. In the first instance of `"blockname1"`: `blocks["blockname1"]`. Awk find that index and because it isn't found assumes `""` (also considered zero). Now, in awk `n = var++` is equivalent to `{n=var;var++}`, so `n==""` and `blocks["blockname1"]==1`. Finally `file=block (n? "_" n: "")` is the same as `{file=block;if(n!="") file+="_" n}`.

Comment: I wasn't even aware a string is a valid indexing variable and of is this reduced if-statement - very helpful, thanks again. I'm saddened I cannot give you the "accepted answer" here: despite me going to adopt this approach as it fulfils my initial task, it doesn't answer the question above (interpretation of condition in while loop) - it would go against my understanding of this sites Q&A system. Yet, I learned a lot - thanks again.